# Why CPLEX outputs different results on different machines?

Tags: .net, mathematical-optimization, cplex

When I run .NET 4 application which uses CPLEX, I get different outputs on different machines. On my development machine CPLEX outputs one result (which is abnormal and stuck at some large value), and on all other machines, result is OK.

First, I thought that it has something to do with OS, and since I have both Windows 7 x64 and Windows 8 x64 on my development machine, I tried running application on both systems. Result is the same - faulty.

Then I tried running on two different desktop machines, and it works OK. I even tried inside virtual machine, with Windows 7 guest on my development machine, and in all those cases, result is OK.

How to fix this issue? How can I debug what is going on? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Additional info:

- My development machine is Asus N73N laptop with Intel Core i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz, 4 Cores, 8 Logical Processors and 8GB RAM.
- CPLEX used: v12.4

Here is the faulty output from my development machine:

```
IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio Commercial Edition                         
Tried aggregator 1 time.
MIP Presolve eliminated 125 rows and 0 columns.
MIP Presolve modified 15000 coefficients.
Reduced MIP has 28795 rows, 14520 columns, and 965648 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 14520 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Probing time =    0.05 sec.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
Presolve time =    1.39 sec.
Found feasible solution after 1.48 sec.  Objective = 4.5736e+016
Probing time =    0.03 sec.
Clique table members: 14520.
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 8 threads.
Root relaxation solution time =    2.70 sec.

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                      4.57357e+016                   1870     ---
*     0+    0                      2.93779e+016                   1870     ---
      0     0  1.54596e+015   811  2.93779e+016  1.54596e+015     1870   94.74%
*     0+    0                      5.78471e+015  1.54596e+015     2258   73.28%
      0     0  1.59388e+015   942  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 377     2258   72.45%
      0     0  1.65120e+015   813  5.78471e+015 ZeroHalf: 216     2590   71.46%
      0     0  1.67178e+015   968  5.78471e+015 ZeroHalf: 285     2857   71.10%
      0     0  1.71285e+015   957  5.78471e+015 ZeroHalf: 123     3241   70.39%
      0     0  1.73687e+015   991  5.78471e+015 ZeroHalf: 148     3642   69.97%
      0     0  1.76181e+015   997  5.78471e+015  ZeroHalf: 50     4048   69.54%
      0     0  1.77762e+015   976  5.78471e+015  ZeroHalf: 23     4344   69.27%
      0     0  1.78664e+015   977  5.78471e+015  ZeroHalf: 22     4601   69.11%
      0     0  1.80055e+015   994  5.78471e+015  ZeroHalf: 75     4943   68.87%
      0     0  1.80615e+015   993  5.78471e+015   ZeroHalf: 9     5143   68.78%
      0     0  1.81464e+015   996  5.78471e+015  ZeroHalf: 33     5440   68.63%
      0     0  1.82294e+015   991  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 27     5765   68.49%
      0     0  1.83208e+015   989  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 18     6104   68.33%
      0     0  1.84944e+015   946  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 182     6698   68.03%
      0     0  1.88828e+015   956  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 269     7432   67.36%
      0     0  1.89984e+015   971  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 118     7822   67.16%
      0     0  1.91068e+015   985  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 45     8155   66.97%
      0     0  1.92274e+015   980  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 40     8597   66.76%
      0     0  1.94969e+015   977  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 121     9295   66.30%
      0     0  1.95749e+015   970  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 69     9682   66.16%
      0     0  1.96689e+015   978  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 42    10093   66.00%
      0     0  1.97224e+015   980  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 30    10392   65.91%
      0     0  1.97649e+015   978  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 13    10622   65.83%
      0     0  1.98557e+015   976  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 50    10876   65.68%
      0     0  1.99259e+015   987  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 46    11183   65.55%
      0     0  2.00116e+015   987  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 77    11494   65.41%
      0     0  2.01149e+015   990  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 37    11921   65.23%
      0     0  2.01969e+015   976  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 60    12286   65.09%
      0     0  2.02492e+015   966  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 43    12578   65.00%
      0     0  2.03316e+015   969  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 84    12881   64.85%
      0     0  2.04175e+015   971  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 52    13174   64.70%
      0     0  2.05273e+015   964  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 68    13649   64.51%
      0     0  2.05591e+015   966  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 23    13902   64.46%
      0     0  2.06170e+015   964  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 43    14235   64.36%
      0     0  2.06574e+015   971  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 46    14481   64.29%
      0     0  2.07500e+015   952  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 47    14890   64.13%
      0     0  2.08393e+015   941  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 53    15280   63.98%
      0     0  2.09065e+015   948  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 36    15601   63.86%
      0     0  2.09803e+015   955  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 104    16015   63.73%
      0     0  2.10316e+015   944  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 63    16384   63.64%
      0     0  2.11460e+015   948  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 76    16846   63.45%
      0     0  2.12942e+015   956  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 97    17366   63.19%
      0     0  2.16151e+015   931  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 327    18262   62.63%
      0     0  2.17502e+015   930  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 120    18714   62.40%
      0     0  2.27173e+015   884  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 385    20411   60.73%
      0     0  2.29553e+015   899  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 134    21117   60.32%
      0     0  2.30977e+015   920  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 71    21621   60.07%
      0     0  2.31979e+015   909  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 38    22064   59.90%
      0     0  2.32293e+015   911  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 33    22333   59.84%
      0     0  2.32804e+015   908  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 60    22682   59.76%
      0     0  2.33324e+015   906  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 43    22991   59.67%
      0     0  2.34725e+015   909  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 22    23332   59.42%
      0     0  2.35327e+015   903  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 72    23571   59.32%
      0     0  2.36485e+015   889  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 61    23938   59.12%
      0     0  2.37310e+015   884  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 45    24319   58.98%
      0     0  2.39039e+015   885  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 79    24958   58.68%
      0     0  2.39677e+015   901  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 56    25186   58.57%
      0     0  2.40149e+015   885  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 41    25442   58.49%
      0     0  2.40325e+015   883  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 60    25617   58.46%
      0     0  2.41812e+015   894  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 84    26070   58.20%
      0     0  2.42607e+015   903  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 68    26474   58.06%
      0     0  2.52725e+015   844  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 524    28147   56.31%
      0     0  2.55516e+015   835  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 196    28727   55.83%
      0     0  3.23302e+015   654  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 889    30777   44.11%
      0     0  3.32795e+015   604  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 337    31390   42.47%
      0     0  3.37780e+015   686  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 212    31791   41.61%
      0     0  3.41202e+015   701  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 121    32148   41.02%
      0     0  3.52260e+015   654  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 398    33114   39.10%
      0     0  3.57604e+015   639  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 244    33613   38.18%
      0     0  3.61288e+015   625  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 235    34098   37.54%
      0     0  3.67035e+015   615  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 163    34491   36.55%
      0     0  3.73087e+015   663  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 157    35105   35.50%
      0     0  3.75834e+015   668  5.78471e+015     Cuts: 144    35530   35.03%
      0     0  3.77753e+015   662  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 93    35899   34.70%
      0     0  3.81446e+015   660  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 82    36310   34.06%
      0     0  3.83284e+015   648  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 76    36608   33.74%
      0     0  3.84779e+015   656  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 58    36845   33.48%
      0     0  3.85941e+015   639  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 67    37084   33.28%
      0     0  3.87033e+015   649  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 40    37284   33.09%
      0     0  3.87967e+015   662  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 32    37422   32.93%
      0     0  3.88305e+015   666  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 24    37577   32.87%
      0     0  3.89084e+015   654  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 59    37771   32.74%
      0     0  3.89489e+015   654  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 38    37968   32.67%
      0     0  3.90160e+015   669  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 55    38172   32.55%
      0     0  3.90440e+015   663  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 40    38329   32.50%
      0     0  3.90794e+015   660  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 27    38492   32.44%
      0     0  3.91249e+015   661  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 31    38662   32.36%
      0     0  3.91569e+015   673  5.78471e+015      Cuts: 32    38814   32.31%
      0     2  3.91569e+015   673  5.78471e+015  3.91569e+015    38814   32.31%
Elapsed real time = 312.08 sec. (tree size =  0.01 MB, solutions = 3)
      1     3  4.19433e+015   728  5.78471e+015  3.91569e+015    41427   32.31%
      2     2        cutoff        5.78471e+015  3.91569e+015    43784   32.31%
      3     3  4.35193e+015   730  5.78471e+015  3.91569e+015    45337   32.31%
      4     2        cutoff        5.78471e+015  3.91569e+015    46000   32.31%
      5     3  4.52240e+015   741  5.78471e+015  3.91569e+015    47554   32.31%
      6     2        cutoff        5.78471e+015  3.91569e+015    49263   32.31%
      7     3  4.66098e+015   799  5.78471e+015  3.91569e+015    51056   32.31%
      8     2        cutoff        5.78471e+015  3.91569e+015    51943   32.31%
      9     3  4.85025e+015   807  5.78471e+015  3.91569e+015    52422   32.31%
     12     2        cutoff        5.78471e+015  3.91569e+015    53363   32.31%
Elapsed real time = 350.88 sec. (tree size =  0.01 MB, solutions = 3)
     15     3  5.59278e+015   896  5.78471e+015  3.91569e+015    54625   32.31%

Clique cuts applied:  1901
Implied bound cuts applied:  160
Zero-half cuts applied:  150

Root node processing (before b&c):
Real time             =  310.11
Parallel b&c, 8 threads:
Real time             =   39.39
Sync time (average)   =    0.00
Wait time (average)   =    0.00
                          -------
Total (root+branch&cut) =  349.50 sec.


inst\instance.txt 00:05:50.9629598        5,78471010310452E+15

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

And here is the normal output from all other machines:

```
IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio Commercial Edition                         
Tried aggregator 1 time.
MIP Presolve eliminated 129 rows and 0 columns.
MIP Presolve modified 15480 coefficients.
Reduced MIP has 28791 rows, 14520 columns, and 965163 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 14520 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Probing time =    0.03 sec.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
Presolve time =    1.51 sec.
Found feasible solution after 1.62 sec.  Objective = 5170425.9868
Probing time =    0.05 sec.
Clique table members: 14520.
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 8 threads.
Root relaxation solution time =    4.82 sec.

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                      5170425.9868                   2742     ---
*     0+    0                      2176197.5073                   2742     ---
      0     0   963286.8006  1320  2176197.5073   963286.8006     2742   55.74%
*     0+    0                      1742629.0387   963286.8006     3146   44.72%
      0     0   968918.1899  1292  1742629.0387     Cuts: 180     3146   44.40%
      0     0   972621.9253  1285  1742629.0387  ZeroHalf: 36     3543   44.19%
      0     0   974930.7260  1336  1742629.0387 ZeroHalf: 157     3934   44.05%
      0     0   975330.5044  1344  1742629.0387   ZeroHalf: 9     4042   44.03%
      0     0   976752.3324  1344  1742629.0387  ZeroHalf: 23     4298   43.95%
      0     0   977523.1431  1375  1742629.0387  ZeroHalf: 13     4523   43.91%
      0     0   978030.2843  1358  1742629.0387   ZeroHalf: 7     4732   43.88%
      0     0   978582.8390  1290  1742629.0387      Cuts: 13     4897   43.84%
      0     0   979462.4757  1394  1742629.0387      Cuts: 22     5107   43.79%
      0     0   980081.0140  1361  1742629.0387      Cuts: 16     5256   43.76%
      0     0   986296.0889  1453  1742629.0387     Cuts: 135     6066   43.40%
      0     0   987753.3557  1412  1742629.0387     Cuts: 105     6386   43.32%
      0     0   988885.7034  1442  1742629.0387      Cuts: 57     6694   43.25%
      0     0   989742.4516  1434  1742629.0387      Cuts: 27     6924   43.20%
      0     0   990497.2364  1434  1742629.0387      Cuts: 45     7178   43.16%
*     0+    0                      1402648.1251   990497.2364     7489   29.38%
      0     0   991849.2315  1437  1402648.1251     Cuts: 288     7489   29.29%
      0     0  1243733.1371   593  1402648.1251    Cuts: 2446    12636   11.33%
      0     0  1276887.2546   583  1402648.1251     Cuts: 556    14078    8.97%
      0     0  1296511.1088   701  1402648.1251     Cuts: 600    14813    7.57%
      0     0  1305221.3720   679  1402648.1251     Cuts: 193    15488    6.95%
      0     0  1309747.0795   660  1402648.1251     Cuts: 139    15848    6.62%
      0     0  1318085.1042   725  1402648.1251      Cuts: 43    16281    6.03%
      0     0  1323312.2600   747  1402648.1251      Cuts: 55    16728    5.66%
      0     0  1325171.8791   677  1402648.1251      Cuts: 23    17033    5.52%
      0     0  1326274.8424   704  1402648.1251      Cuts: 19    17265    5.44%
      0     0  1327853.0467   714  1402648.1251      Cuts: 20    17519    5.33%
      0     0  1328078.7180   687  1402648.1251       Cuts: 6    17621    5.32%
      0     0  1328705.5414   702  1402648.1251      Cuts: 18    17768    5.27%
      0     0  1329753.6276   716  1402648.1251      Cuts: 15    17988    5.20%
      0     0  1330728.0832   705  1402648.1251   ZeroHalf: 5    18165    5.13%
      0     0  1331208.9314   707  1402648.1251      Cuts: 15    18322    5.09%
      0     0  1331935.6017   709  1402648.1251   ZeroHalf: 5    18432    5.04%
      0     0  1332438.9391   738  1402648.1251   ZeroHalf: 4    18536    5.01%
      0     0  1332565.6221   712  1402648.1251       Cuts: 3    18578    5.00%
      0     0  1332961.2175   712  1402648.1251   ZeroHalf: 7    18653    4.97%
      0     2  1332962.3523   711  1402648.1251  1332962.3523    18656    4.97%
Elapsed real time = 136.63 sec. (tree size =  0.01 MB, solutions = 4)
      1     3  1355937.1387   819  1402648.1251  1332962.3523    20475    4.97%
      2     2        cutoff        1402648.1251  1332962.3523    20810    4.97%
      3     3  1373864.6210   889  1402648.1251  1332962.3523    21989    4.97%
      5     3  1391805.4913   902  1402648.1251  1332962.3523    22812    4.97%
      6     2        cutoff        1402648.1251  1332962.3523    24410    4.97%
      7     1        cutoff        1402648.1251  1332962.3523    25377    4.97%
      8     0        cutoff        1402648.1251  1332962.3523    26154    4.97%

Clique cuts applied:  2880
Implied bound cuts applied:  73
Zero-half cuts applied:  97

Root node processing (before b&c):
Real time             =  134.80
Parallel b&c, 8 threads:
Real time             =   16.44
Sync time (average)   =    0.00
Wait time (average)   =    0.00
                      -------
Total (root+branch&cut) =  151.24 sec.


inst\instance.txt 00:02:32.8137404        1402648.12514155

0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should be absolutely sure that you're solving exactly the same problem.

Looking at the logs, it seems that the problem CPLEX is solving is different.
For example presolve eliminates 125 rows in the first case and 129 in the second, and modifies 15000 coefficients in the first case and 15480 in the second; also the reduced MIP seems different:
28795 rows, 14520 columns, and 965648 nonzeros in the first case and 28791 rows, 14520 columns, and 965163 nonzeros in the second case.

I'm pretty sure CPLEX presolve is totally deterministic and definitely platform independent.
So in my opinion, for some reason you're generating two different problems.

You could try to export the problem to LP file on dev and test machines, then check if the two files are equal (or even try to solve the .LP file generated on test machine to the development one and check the log)

Anyway, on IBM site there's a section about ["runs reproducibility"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21399979).
They state that on different HW architectures results can actually change, but optimal solution objective value (of course) remains the same.
However, I really doubt this is your case (values are too different), so I'd compare the exported LP problems to see if there are any difference between development and test machines.

Comment: You are right. Turns out it was a different problem after all. Reason: different regional settings. Changed code from double.parse(a_number) to double.parse(a_number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).